# Extra space around shape when extracting a png

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png, mask, background-removal

I have a photos, which I want to have in round shapes like the example presented below. Anyways, when making the clipping mask in Illustrator CS6, the extra space of the image around the circle stays. So, when I extract a png file, this is what I have-the circle with transparent background, but extra space around it. I tried to just crop the file, but I have lots of them, so this would take a lot of time. I wonder if there is a way to get rid of the space inside Illustrator.

Comment: Make sure that in your document properties you have "Align to Pixel Grid" selected so that your work and masks will be aligned to the pixel grid. You may be seeing Illustrator grabbing some extra pixels because it is not currently aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create your circular clipping mask, select it, then go to your artboard tool,

[image]

then in the presets above, just use fit to selected art.

[image]

Finally, all you have to do when you're saving your PNG, is to make sure "use artboards" is checked.

[image]

Comment: One more question. When I do that, my artboard is of size 140x140, however, the png I export is 141x140. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try None as option, not Art Optimized, nor Type Optimized.

Comment: Please add a screenshot and explain what the three Options you mentioned do ..  One line answer is a little bit short ...